# Aurelia - Require feature to handle reference tracking of a particular filter result when applying multiple filters?

Tags: sorting, binding, pagination, filtering, aurelia

Have a table with the filtering and sorting like so:

```
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="row"
                        repeat.for="repo of repos |
                                    filter:searchField.value:filterGitHubTable |
                                    sort: {propertyName: column.value, direction: direction.value} |
                                    pageData:{currentPage: pageNumber, pageSize:pageSize}">
                        <td class="col-xs-3">${repo.name}</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-3">${repo.stargazers_count}</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-3">${repo.forks_count}</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-3">${repo.open_issues}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

In my pager code below its setup as

```
<pagination model.bind="repos"
            page-size.bind="pageSize"
            pageclick.delegate="handlePageClick($event)"
            pagination-class="pg-bluegrey"></pagination>
```

How to make the pagination element model bind to the reference of a filter result 'after the sorting' but 'before it does the next filter for pagination data'?

The reason is once have pagination data, I don't have the whole filter result to bind with the pagination element. How would I keeping track of page numbering when applying the filter on the table result?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't understood your question. Could you reproduce your problem in this gist https://gist.run/?id=c32f322b1f56e6f0a83679512247af7b Then it will be easier to understand

Comment: Hi Fabio, in this example applying three filters to the repos array - repos | filter | sort | paging. How do I apply the results of the filter to bind to the pagination element (model.bind) from the sort filter, not the pagination part

Comment: in the `filterChanged` event you can update the variable bound to the pagination element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little trick you might be able to use here. You can use a `hidden` HTML element to sort of "hold on" to an intermediate version of your data. Aurelia allows you to attach arbitrary attributes to any element, and by using the `ref` attribute, we can attach the element itself to our viewmodel. We can then access any data we've attached to this element anywhere we want in our view or viewmodel. Check this out:

```
<input type="hidden" ref="filteredAndSorted" 
       data.bind="repos |
                  filter:searchField.value:filterGitHubTable |
                  sort: {propertyName: column.value, direction: direction.value}" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row" repeat.for="filteredAndSorted.data |
                                pageData:{currentPage: pageNumber, pageSize:pageSize}">
      <td class="col-xs-3">${repo.name}</td>
      <td class="col-xs-3">${repo.stargazers_count}</td>
      <td class="col-xs-3">${repo.forks_count}</td>
      <td class="col-xs-3">${repo.open_issues}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<pagination model.bind="filteredAndSorted.data" 
            page-size.bind="pageSize" 
            pageclick.delegate="handlePageClick($event)" 
            pagination-class="pg-bluegrey">
</pagination>
```

I'm betting this is what will help you. Sorry it took so long to answer, I've been quite busy the last few days doing Aurelia training.

Comment: Very good response. It actually worked like a charm! Awesome and notice this tip good for solving other problems, storing temporary data down the page and reuse later, very nice. Thank you, let me know if writing a book